# Python Convert Integers to YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS Format

Tags: python, pandas, date

I need to convert a df with a data column of integers and convert this to the following format in the current year: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS. I have a DF that looks like this:

```
       Date   LT Mean
0     7  5.491916
1     8  5.596823
2     9  5.793934
3    10  7.501096
4    11  8.152358
5    12  8.426322
```

And, I need it to look like this using the current year 2020:

```
   Date   LT Mean
0     2020-07-01  5.491916
1     2020-08-01  5.596823
2     2020-09-01  5.793934
3     2020-10-01  7.501096
4     2020-11-01  8.152358
5     2020-12-01  8.426322
```

I have not been able to find a reference for converting a single integer used for the date and converting it into the yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss format i need. Thank you,

Comment: What does `Date` represent? _I have not been able to find a reference for converting a single integer used for the date and converting it into the yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss format i need._ Have you checked the Pandas documentation? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: pandas has function `to_datetime` to convert to object `datetime` which can me more useful then strings like `2020-07-01`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use pandas [to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) function. Assuming your `Date` column represents the month, you can use like this:

```py
df['Date'] = pandas.to_datetime(df["Date"], format='%m').apply(lambda dt: dt.replace(year=2020))
```

Then if you need transform the column to string in the specified format:

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s')
```

Comment: thank you! can you explain to me how the lambda function works to format the date into yyyy-mm-dd format even though the format is set to %m?

Comment: the function `to_datetime` will generate a datetime object. Using the `%m` format will set the other properties of the date (year, day, hour, minute, second) to a default value, in the case of the year will be 1900. So the lambda is used to change that using the `datetime.replace` function.